# Dynamically query a table in generic repo

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm setting up a method that can query up to 3 different tables with the same table structure dependent on a run time value. I want to have a single query that can substitute the table type.

I have provided some sample code of my current attempt, if anyone has experience with a similar task then any guidance would be welcomed!

```
IGenericRepository<T> where T : class

public void Foo(int val)
{
     object table; // needs to store the type of table
     if (val == 1)
        table = typeof(table1);
     if (val == 2)
        table = typeof(table2);
      if (val == 3)
        table = typeof(table3);

     var result = _genericRepo<table>().GetQueryable();
}
```

Comment: "identical but different" say what? :D this method is so much anty SOLID, do you even need generic repository there? https://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/

Comment: you could use generic method public void Foo<T>() where T is your table type